# How to refer to the program name in help strings?

Tags: rust, clap

In my CLI program the usage examples are provided as part of the help message. Using the `clap` derive interface I can do the following

```rust
#[derive(Parser, Debug, Default)]
#[clap( after_help = "EXAMPLES:\n  $ foo abc.txt")]
pub struct CmdLine {...}
```

The program name `foo` is hard coded in the literal string above.

How can I avoid hard-coding the program name and get it dynamically; for example, from `std::env::args[0]` or `clap::App:get_bin_name()` ?

Comment: You could probably implement the required traits for CLI help manually, you should look at the documentation of ``clap`` macro and the `Parser` trait.

Answer (score 1):

clap provides a macro called [crate_name!](https://docs.rs/clap/3.1.8/clap/macro.crate_name.html) that will take the name from your `cargo.toml`.

For example, suppose you have this in your `cargo.toml`.

```
[package]
name = "myapp"
description = "myapp description"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = [ "John Doe" ]
```

Then, in your application, you can fetch these values using the macros, like this:

```rust
    let matches = Command::new(clap::crate_name!())
        .version(clap::crate_version!())
        .author(clap::crate_authors!())
        .about(clap::crate_description!())
        //
        // abbreviated
        //
```

The section below is appended to respond to the original poster's specific question. See the comments below for context. Also, including some learnings as well.

---

***Appended per the discussion in comments.***

Based on the comments/discussion below, initial thought is just to stuff the binary name from the arguments into a string and pass into the `after_help()` function.  For example, something like this:

```rust
let bin_name = std::env:args().into_iter().next().unwrap();
let matches = Command::new(bin_name)
    .after_help(format!("Text that includes {}", bin_name)) // This won't compile
    .get_matches();
```

Taking this approach, you quickly run into a lifetime requirement in the function signature for `after_help()`. From clap's repo:

```rust
pub fn after_help<S: Into<&'help str>>(mut self, help: S)
```

In fact, if you look, there are many fields in the `Command` struct that have the lifetime annotation (`&'help`) on them. The `Command::new()` method doesn't have this lifetime annotation so it worked fine to just pass it `bin_name` as shown above.

Below is an abbreviated solution that dynamically generates *after-help* text in a manner that adheres to the lifetime requirements. Assuming a clean binary (application), called "foo", add the following code:

**cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A foo cli application"
authors = [ "John Doe" ]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "3.1.6", features = ["cargo"] }
```

**main.rs**

```rust
fn main() {
    // Get the binary name from the command line
    let bin_name = std::env::args().into_iter().next().unwrap();

    // Construct text that will be used in after_help.
    let after_help_text = format!(
        "Some after-help text that includes the binary name: {}",
        bin_name
    );

    // clap, by default, will reference the name of your package. So, if you're
    // doing the above, you might as well override the usage text too so you're
    // being consistent.
    let usage_text = format!("{}", bin_name);

    if let Err(e) = foo::get_args(bin_name, after_help_text, usage_text).and_then(foo::run) {
        eprintln!("{e}");
        std::process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

**lib.rs**

```rust
use clap::{ArgMatches, Command};

pub fn get_args(
    bin_name: String,
    after_help_text: String,
    usage_text: String,
) -> std::io::Result<ArgMatches> {
    let matches = Command::new(bin_name)
        .override_usage(usage_text.as_str())
        .version(clap::crate_version!())
        .after_help(after_help_text.as_str())
        .author(clap::crate_authors!())
        .about(clap::crate_description!())
        // add and configure args...
        .get_matches();

    Result::Ok(matches)
}

pub fn run(matches: ArgMatches) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    // Do your CLI logic here based on matches.
    Ok(())
}
```

Running the solution ( `cargo run -- --help` ) will produce the following output:

```
./foo 0.1.0
John Doe
A foo cli application

USAGE:
    ./foo

OPTIONS:
    -h, --help       Print help information
    -V, --version    Print version information

Some after-help text that includes the binary name: ./foo
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. `crate_name!` macro still gives a compile time value (taken from Cargo.toml). I am looking for the runtime name of the program taken from `args[0]` the same way as `clap` does in the USAGE string.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see now what you're asking.  So, something like `let matches = Command::new(std::env:args().into_iter().next().unwrap()).get_matches()`.  I just tried this and it seems to work.

Comment: yes, your code expands to the runtime program name as I want it. Now, how do I stick this value into `after_help` string `#[clap( after_help = "EXAMPLES:\n  $ foo abc.txt")]` to replace hard-coded name `foo` ? All the examples that I found use literal strings (no runtime content possible).

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck, I took another look at this to see how this could be done and have a solution. I'm going to edit my answer above shortly to include this. Personally, I'm not a fan of the solution I came up with, but, I'm also not aware of your set of requirements so not judging at all. Still, I found it to be an interesting question/problem and wanted to see if I could work it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great in the 'clap builder' API context. Is it possible to extend your solution to the new 'clap derive' API?

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck, I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and eventually stumbled on [Cargo environment variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html). Here is the description of the variable of interest:

> CARGO_CRATE_NAME — The name of the crate that is currently being compiled. It is the name of the Cargo target with - converted to _, such as the name of the library, binary, example, integration test, or benchmark.

Here is a trivial sample project which demonstrates how to use it to solve the problem you presented:

```
# tree sample/
sample/
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    └── bin
        └── different-name.rs

3 directories, 3 files
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "sample"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
clap = { version = "4.4.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

**different-name.rs**

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(name = env!("CARGO_CRATE_NAME"))]
struct Args {}

fn main() {
    Args::parse();
}
```

Running the solution (`cargo run -- --help`) produces the following output:

```
Usage: different-name

Options:
  -h, --help  Print help
```

Note that the [`env!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) macro expands to a static string <s>literal</s> slice at compile time (see edit below). There are similar options for evaluating at runtime, though you probably want compile time for your use case.

My use case is a cargo project containing multiple binary crates automating application packaging and deployment, so I can confirm this works correctly on a per-crate basis.

---

Edit: I just wanted to clarify a point about the `env!()` macro. It does execute at compile time, but it returns a `&'static str`, which is a static string slice, not a static string literal. For most purposes, there isn't much difference, but some things like the [`concat!()`](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) macro only accept literals. If you're like me and want to create const-like variables using values retrieved with `env!()`, you can use the [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate.